# Retrieving audio codec use in soft phone in C#

Tags: c#, c, voip

I'm creating a program that would would determine what audio codec is being used. I used X-lite for my soft phone. any Idea?? or should I use open source soft phone?

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to understand. Do you want to create a program that can communicate with another program called X-lite? Or write your own voip program?

Comment: Yes sir I want to create a program that can communicate with another program  called X-lite..I want to know what audio audio codec is being use..

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to integrate directly with the xlite softphone your best bet would be to use a packet capture tool and extract the codec from an [RTP](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3550.txt) packet. Specifically the RTP header Payload Type field will indicate the codec in use.